# Detect when 'New E-mail' or 'Send' button is clicked in outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, python

I'm trying to write up a python script that could detect when a button ('New E-mail' or 'Send') is clicked in Microsoft Outlook - > and then do something if that is true.

Is there any way that Windows logs something like this which I can use a python script to detect? Any better way of doing this (preferably still using python)? Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain the end result? It sounds like simple rules would already do what you want, and python is not at all required.

Comment: You can definitely use Rules Wizard to run a script (not Python, but VBA for Outlook) when an e-mail goes into the Outbox. It wouldn't necessarily be the Send button as you can also use Ctrl+Enter to Send.